# Configuring a task queue and instance for non urgent work

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using an F4 instance (because of memory needs) with automatic scheduling to do some background processing. It is run from a task queue. It takes 40s to 60s to complete each invocation. Because of the high memory needs, each instance should only handle one request at a time.

The action that needs to be done is not urgent. If it doesn't get scheduled for 30 minutes that isn't a problem. Even 60 minutes is acceptable and I'd rather make use of that time rather than spin up more instances. However, if the service gets popular and the is getting more than 60 requests an hour I want to spin up more instances to make sure there isn't more than a 60 minute wait.

I am having trouble figuring out how to configure the instance and queue parameters to keep my costs down but be able to scale in that way. My initial thought was something like this:

```
<queue>
    <name>non-urgent-queue</name>
    <target>slow-service</target>
    <rate>1/m</rate>
    <bucket-size>1</bucket-size>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>


<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>0</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>0</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>20m</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>1h</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```

First of all those latency settings are invalid, but I can't find documentation on the valid range or units. Can anyone direct me to that info?

Secondly, if I understand the queue settings correctly, this configuration would limit it to 60 invocations an hour getting to the service, even if the task queue had 60+ jobs waiting.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it. I use a slow queue and a fast queue configured like this:

```
<queue>
    <name>slow-queue</name>
    <target>pdf-service</target>
    <rate>2/m</rate>
    <bucket-size>1</bucket-size>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
  </queue>
<queue>
    <name>fast-queue</name>
    <target>pdf-service</target>
    <rate>10/m</rate>
    <bucket-size>1</bucket-size>
    <max-concurrent-requests>5</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

The max-concurrent-requests in the slow queue ensures only one task will run at a time, so there will only be one instance active.

Before I post to the slow queue I check to see how many items are already on the queue. The result may not be totally reliable, but for my purposes it is sufficient. In java:

```
QueueStatistics queueStats = queue.fetchStatistics();
if(queueStats.getNumTasks()<30) { 
   //post to slow queue
} else {
   //post to fast queue
}
```

So when my slow queue gets too full, I post to the fast queue which allows concurrent requests.

The instance is configured like this:

```
<automatic-scaling>
   <min-idle-instances>0</min-idle-instances>
   <max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
   <min-pending-latency>15s</min-pending-latency>
   <max-pending-latency>15s</max-pending-latency>
   <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```

So it will create new instances as slowly as possible (15s is the max latency) and make sure only one process runs on an instance at a time.

With this configuration I'll have a max of 6 instances at a time but that should do about 500/hr. I could increase the rate and concurrent requests to do more.

The negative of this solution is an element of unfairness. Under heavy load, some tasks will be stuck in the slow queue while others will get processed more quickly in the fast queue.

Because of that, I have decreased the max items on the slow queue to 13 so the unfairness won't be so extreme, maybe a 10 minute wait for jobs that go to the slow queue when it is full.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, throttling at the queue level basically defeats the ability to scale when needed. So you can't use the `<rate>` in the queue configuration at the values you have right now, you need to use the value matching the maximum rate you're willing to accept (with you max number of instances running simultaneously):

- the max rate of requests that can go through the queue being limited at 1/min means you can't scale above 60/h
- the `<bucket-size>` set at `1` means no peaks above the rate can be handled (as soon as one task starts the token bucket empties).
- the `<max-concurrent-requests>` set at `1` will basically prevent multiple instances dealing simultaneouly with the queued workload. They may be started by the autoscaler because of the request latencies, but they won't be able to help since only one queue task can be handled at a time.

In the `<automatic-scaling>` section the `<max-concurrent-requests>` set to `1` is good - this ensures no instance handles more than 1 request at a time - which is what you want.

The bad news is that the max values for the latencies appear to be 15s. At least when using the `app.yaml` config for python (but I think it's unlikely for that to differ across language sandboxes):

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
automatic_scaling.min_pending_latency (30s), must be in the range [0.010000s,15.000000s].
--- end server output ---
```

and

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
automatic_scaling.max_pending_latency (60s), must be in the range [0.010000s,15.000000s].
--- end server output ---
```

Which probably also explains why your `5m` and `1h` values aren't accepted - I used `30s` and `60s` and got the above errors.

This means you won't be able to use the autoscaling parameters to tune such a slow-moving processing like you desire.

The only alternative I can think of is to have 2 queues:

- a fast one feeding just trigger tasks for the slow-service jobs, but which your service intercepts and saves in the datastore. Maybe performed by some faster service (you don't want these stuck behind a slow-service job execution as it can cause unnecessary instance launching. Maybe, depending on the rest of your implementation, you can replace this queue completely with just storing the job info in the datastore instead of enqueing tasks in the fast queue.
- a slow one for the actual slow-service job execution tasks

You'd also have a cron job executing once a minute, checking how many triggers are pending in the datastore, decide how much to scale and enqueue the corresponding number of slow-service job tasks in the slow queue. The autoscaler would simply bring up the corresponding number of instances (if needed). Low latency autoscaling configs would be desirable in this case - you already decided how you want your app to scale.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what the queue settings would do and the info on the autoscaling parameter ranges. The two queue idea is interesting. Still trying to get my head around it. The cron job gave me another idea of trying to manipulate the queue rate. It looks like there was some kind of queue manage api that was deprecated and the new one isn't available yet, so not sure if that was possible or not....